# clear browsers cache js files by code

Tags: javascript, caching

In order to clear browsers cache from my js files  ,
I added the version number from my assemblyInfo to the src attribute :

Something like :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MyJs.js?version=1.1.5")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think that this code force the js code to refresh only when I change the version number. 
However it seems that it refreshes every time although I don't change the version number .

Any idea why it happens ? How to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: "However it seems that it refreshes" --- how about looking at headers and knowing for sure? Programming is not about magic and guesses, but about facts.

Comment: What is the actual `src` that's returned?

Comment: zerkms - I checked it , it refreshes every time.

Comment: What do you mean ? src simply returns my javascript file .

Comment: @TwTw: how did you check it? Have you checked **headers**?

Comment: zerkms  - I used firebug , what am I supposed to see in headers?

Comment: @TwTw: what is the status code, what is in caching-related headers (both request and response)